# SQL - nest a count within a case when statement

Tags: sql, case, teradata, case-when

SO I'm trying to to count the number of schedule numbers if they appear more than once in a table but getting an "cannot nest aggregrate functions" error

This is my code

```
select distinct acd.client_desc,

count(case when (count(tom.schedule_number)>1) then tom.schedule_number end) as "Shared Trailer"


from fact_parcel_movement fpm

inner join account_contract_detail acd
on acd.account_contract_sk = fpm.account_contract_sk

full join transport_order_movement tom
on tom.esp_start_location_code = fpm.parcel_movement_start_transport_location_code

where fpm.PARCEL_MOVEMENT_START_EVENT_SEQ_NO = -1
and fpm.parcel_movement_start_transport_location_code not like 'YDL%'
and fpm.parcel_movement_start_transport_location_code not like 'RETURN'
and fpm.parcel_movement_start_transport_location_code not like '123456'

group by 1
```

Comment: I can't make a suggestion based alone on the query and description.  You may want to add sample data and/or simplify the query.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit.  You have to do your inner count in a derived table, and then your second count from that.  Also, you don't need both distinct and group by.